# constant kernel for Gaussian process

Tags: kernel

Does anyone know the meaning of constant kernel used for Gaussian process? The document of sklearn says it is used to modify the mean of Gaussian process. Isn't the mean zero in Gaussian process generally? I found the constant kernel actually modifies the standard deviation. Why?

Answer (score 2):

In practice, the addition of the constant to the kernel can be used instead of shifting the mean of the dataset labels **Y**. I have observed this many times.

For example, let's say that I want to fit the smooth function with the **Ymean** = 3.5 using RBF kernel plus constant kernel **σ^2**. In this case, after hyperparameters optimization (via marginal likelihood maximization), the hyperparameter **σ** becomes very close to the **Ymean** value 3.5.

Instead, I can manually subtract the mean and fit the Gaussian process on the new **Y* = Y - Ymean** using the same kernel. In this case, I will obtain the **σ** value close to zero.

Speaking more formally, the meaning of constant in the kernel is exactly the variance on the constant term in the polynomial approximation of our GP-predicted function.

Answer (score 1):

you can find it the reason based on the definition.

Let

> $f(x) \sim GP(m(x)=0, k(x_i, x_j))$

that is to say,

> $E[f(x)] = 0$, $cov[f(x_i), f(x_j)] = k(x_i, x_j)$

If a constant c is added to the kernel,

> $cov[f(x_i), f(x_j)] = E[(f(x_i) - E[f(x_i)])(f(x_j) -E[f(x_i)])]= E[f(x_i)f(x_j)] - m(x_i)m(x_j) = E[f(x_i)f(x_j)] = k(x_i, x_j) + c$

So actually it is the same as a GP with

> $sqrt(c), k(x_i, x_j)$

because

> $cov[f(x_i), f(x_j)] = E[f(x_i)f(x_j)] - m(x_i)m(x_j) = E[f(x_i)f(x_j)] - c = k(x_i, x_j)$

, which it the previous kernel.